# Async code required in event handler

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I have an AngularJS controller that raises events to communicate with the outside world. One of the events is fired to obtain the URL where it should send its data to.

The event handler responds to this event, but it needs to make an AJAX call (using $http) to an external server. This call is asynchronous, but how do I prevent the event from completion, before the AJAX call has completed. As far as I know, I cannot use deferred objects to deal with this. Anyone a good solution?

Comment: Callback is an option?

Comment: I currently use a callback, but it requires a tight connection between my two components. Events would be much more loose, that's why I wanted to move to an event. Now I know, why it was a callback ;-)

Comment: What's the reason for not using deferred objects?

Answer (score 0):

How about you raise a `myEventHasFinishedSuccessfully` event in the success handler of the http call. You can listen out for that event and run any actions that depend on the asynch operation.

This is, in effect, a loosely coupled callback equivalent.